# Unable to start the spyder IDE

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have created an environment in Anaconda using `environment.yml` file. After  activating the environment when I try to open **Spyder IDE** it shows up the following error message.

```
>(virtual_platform) thepro@thepro-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ spyder  
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thepro/anaconda3/envs/virtual_platform/lib/python3.5/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /home/thepro/anaconda3/envs/virtual_platform/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numexpr/../../../libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thepro/anaconda3/envs/virtual_platform/bin/spyder", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
  File "/home/thepro/anaconda3/envs/virtual_platform/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/thepro/anaconda3/envs/virtual_platform/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 92, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/home/thepro/anaconda3/envs/virtual_platform/lib/python3.5/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /home/thepro/anaconda3/envs/virtual_platform/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/../../../libQt5WebKit.so.5: symbol _ZN15QQuickFlickable11contentItemEv, version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Quick.so.5 with link time reference
```

I am unable to sort it out using all previous suggested solutions on using other **gcc** versions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uh, I think that's pretty messed up... You'd better install "raw" Python & Spyder from their official websites.

Comment: Do you have LD_LIBRARY_PATH set?

Comment: No, the path is not set.